# zend 2 translating validation errors

Tags: zend-framework

There are a lot of examples on how to do it on zend 1, but nothing yet on zend 2. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

I am using annotations in the model to define entities. This also does not seem to work: (It does not return mandatory_translation_key anywhere)

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, name="Name")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":100}})
 * @Annotation\ErrorMessage("mandatory_translation_key")
 */
 protected $name;
```